# Android - не получается сцентрировать view в NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

Посмотрите пожалуйста на разметку.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_background"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabvptl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:elevation="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:backgroundTint="#D30A27"
    android:src="@drawable/fabrandom"
/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

И разметка фрагмента `ViewPager`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:id="@+id/squaremask"
            android:background="#D52115"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="80sp"
            android:padding="50dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Все работает (я про прокрутку тулбара), но `TextView` никак не хочет встать в центр

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextView` у Вас уже центрирован в родительском `View`, коим является `RelativeLayout`. Вам нужно центрировать этот `RelativeLayout` в его родительском представлении.

У `RelativeLayout` замените:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

на:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

И еще: у `RelativeLayout` можете удалить атрибут:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

ибо он все равно не используется.

Comment: Спасибо. Не разобрался сразу

Answer (score -2):

В *NestedScroll* попробуйте добавить `android:gravity="center"`.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?